# El navegador rechaza la conexión a Api rest Spring Boot por ser insegura

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, https, certificado-ssl

Estoy intentando acceder a una api rest echa en Spring Boot pero el navegador rechaza la conexión por ser insegura. El mensaje que recibo del navegador es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La api rest esta montada sobre un servidor Ubuntu 20.04 con un Apache Tomcat 10.1.13. La versión de Spring Boot es la 2.6.3. Estoy usando Java 11.
Por otro lado instale un certificado autoformado usando Keytool.

**el appication.properties quedo de la siguiente manera**

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key.alias=ode=https
server.ssl.key-store-type= PKCS12
server.ssl.key-password=123456
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-store=/opt/tomcat/ode-https.p12
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

**En el server.xml de tomcat tengo el conector configurado de esta maneta**

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxParameterCount="2000"

              >
       <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
       <SSLHostConfig>
           <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/ode-https"
                certificateKeystorePassword="123456"
                type="RSA"/>
       </SSLHostConfig>
   </Connector>
```

La aplicación levanta correctamente cuando ejecuto el .jar ´
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen el certificado esta funcionando porque la aplicación se levanta en el puerto 8443 por https como se indica en el application.properties.

Alguna idea de como resolver esto?